# How to move the log in button from right to left?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, bbpress

The bbpress-login button is now floating to the right instead of the desired left: http://epilens.com/login/

I inspected the elements using firepath and saw the following:

```
<div class="bbp-submit-wrapper">
    <button class="button submit user-submit" name="user-submit" tabindex="104" type="submit">Log In</button>
```

As well as this:

```
.bbp-submit-wrapper {
    text-align: right;
}
```

On firefox, when I add the line, the button does shift to the left

```
.bbp-submit-wrapper {
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
}
```

So I entered into the wordpress css.style and at the end I added:

```
.bbp-submit-wrapper {
   float: left;
}
```

But nothing changes, what should I do and why it didn't do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is just using the following code as you said, but with **!important** inside, because I guess there is something that's overriding your changes. Use the *div* before so it is more specific and you don't end with corrupting something other, in case.

```
 div.bbp-submit-wrapper {
    float: left !important;
}
```

Pleae, before everything for first check if you have any caching plugin (W3 Total Cache, WP Super Cache, WP Rocket and so on) and **be sure** to delete it after having added these lines of code, than delete the cache from your browser too or visit your website in Incognito mode.
It is a strange behavior because this is the simplest way to achieve this without problems. 

If it still doesn't work, you could try simply using a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) that overrides original styles - looking at your source it seems that you are using a parent template theme, so I suggest you to use the child one.

Answer (score 0):

Just Easy

```
.bbp-submit-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}
.button.submit.user-submit{
    float: left;
}
```

This will work.!